# Default Route with parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a controller and I don't want my default `Action` or `View` to be named `Index`. I created Action in `TopicsController` as below

```
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult Topics()
{
    var topic = new Topic();
   return View("Topics", topic.GetTopics());
}
```

and it mached to URL `xyz.com/Topics`.

I tried to apply same philosophy to another controller, named, `ModulesController` but now I have got parameter.

```
[ActionName("Index")]
public ActionResult Modules(string id)
{
    var topic = new Topic();
    return View("Modules", topic.GetTopics());
}
```

but now it is saying

> The resource cannot be found.

what I can do so that this action matches URL like `xyz.com/Modules/aaaa`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the Url *xyz.com/Modules/aaaa* change the `Action` name for the `Modules` action to `aaaa` like this:

```
[ActionName("aaaa")]
public ActionResult Modules(string id)
{
    var topic = new Topic();
    return View("Modules", topic.GetTopics());
}
```

FYI - It would be better to avoid naming each action with the `ActionName` filter. At some point it would become difficult to manage. Instead manage the routes in the `RouteConfig` like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Modules",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller="Modules", action="Modules", id=UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

The following Urls will work for the above route:

- xyz.com/Modules/aaaa
- xyz.com/Modules/aaaa/123
- xyz.com/Modules/aaaa?id=123

**Update:**
If you want 'aaaa' to be the parameter and want to access the action with *xyz.com/Modules/aaaa* (where 'aaaa' will be bound as the value to the `Id` variable) then add the following Route to the route table:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Modules",
    url: "Modules/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller="Modules", action="Modules", id=UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Note the value of the `Url` above.

Comment: I want `aaaa` to be parameter name not action name. Can't I do just `ActionName/parameterName` and get action name by default?

Comment: @Imad Yes, you can do that. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Hey, sorry to trouble you again, can we accomplish this using attribute based routing? because my routes are growing quite large using this approach.

Comment: @Imad, Add the following to the Action: `[Route(“Modules/{id}”)]` and remove the `ActionName` filter.